# Most recent introduction to academic debates to vegetarianism and veganism

Tags: ethics, animal-welfare, animals

What are the most recent and comprehensive academic books on vegetarianism, veganism, food ethics etc.?
I am looking for something that would cover the main discussions in the field... something in the lines of "A very short introduction to..."
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

These references might help. All have a philosophical angle.

Emelia Quinn, Thinking Veganism in Literature and Culture : Towards a Vegan Theory, ISBN 10: 3319733796 / ISBN 13: 9783319733791
Published by Springer-Verlag Gmbh Jun 2018.

James Stewart, Vegetarianism and Animal Ethics in Contemporary Buddhism, ISBN 10: 1138493368 / ISBN 13: 9781138493360
Published by Taylor & Francis Ltd, United Kingdom, 2018.

David Christopher Lane, Porphyry s on the Abstinence from Animal Food, ISBN 10: 1565436369 / ISBN 13: 9781565436367
Published by Mount San Antonio College/Philosophy Group, 2017.

Mark Hawthorne, A Vegan Ethic, ISBN 10: 1785354027 / ISBN 13: 9781785354021
Published by Changemakers Books 2016-07-29, Winchester, UK, 2016.

Steven McMullen, Animals and the Economy, ISBN 10: 1137434732 / ISBN 13: 9781137434739
Published by Palgrave Macmillan Aug 2016, 2016.

---

As for *a single book* on vegetarianism *and* veganism one recommendation is :

Lee Hall, On Their Own Terms: Animal Liberation for the 21st Century, ISBN 10: 1530341256 / ISBN 13: 9781530341252
Published by Createspace Independent Publishing Platform, United States, 2016

Or you might start with Mark Hawthorne, A Vegan Ethic, and work outwards from there. See what it says about vegetarianism and follow up its references to vegetarianism. Can't think of a perfect all-in-one, I'm afraid.